# How to apply list of functions to list of corresponding parameters *fast*

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Given is a list of function handles in Python, say:

```
f = [f1, f2, f3, f4]
```

and a corresponding list of parameters:

```
a = [a1, a2, a3, a4]
```

**Problem**
I want to *quickly* compute: [f1(a1), f2(a2), f3(a3), f4(a4)]. I tried list comprehension, but for my application it was too slow. Is there a more natural way/numpy-fast way to do this? I am thinking some sort of vectorization.

Comment: Have you tried: `[func(param) for func, param in zip(f, a)]`? I don't understand how `numpy` can optimize `zip` in this case.

Comment: Before anyone can evaluate whether it can be vectorized, you need to show what the function does. Please give an example input and output, along with the function

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for the comment, yeah I may have to go a layer deeper, good point, I guess I was roughly thinking of maybe stacking f and a in a 2d array and apply the columns "to each other" in some sense.

Comment: Having a list of functions for each item in your array probably means you've gone past the point of vectorization. There are some misleading names in the `numpy` library for methods that are nothing more than python `for` loops, so we need to see what those functions do (assuming they are basically the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` for associating elements of same index across two lists.

```
res = [func(x) for func, x in zip(f, a)]
```

From there, your bottleneck would probably be the function calls.

Answer (score 1):

bottleneck is probably the function calls. Not sure about the result sizes which might impact performance through memory management. Therefore be sure to understand the difference between list comprehension and an generator expression. If memory is an issue here, go for a generator expression:

```
res = (fun(x) for fun, x in zip(f, a))
```